# Get null value after dialog show

Tags: android

Here is my problem, see below codes

```
PlayListNameDialog newPlaylistDialog=new PlayListNameDialog();
newPlaylistDialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"new playlist");
ArrayList<String> tempAdd=new ArrayList();
tempAdd.add(currentSong);
QueryMusic.playlistCollection.put(QueryMusic.playlistNameList.get(0),tempAdd);
SimpleMusicMainActivity.fragmentPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and codes in dialog when ok button pressed,

```
okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            plName=playListName.getText().toString();
            if (!QueryMusic.playlistNameList.contains(plName))
                QueryMusic.playlistNameList.add(plName);
            if (!plName.isEmpty()&&plName.trim().length()>0)
                PlayListNameDialog.this.dismiss();
            else
                Snackbar.make(okButton,"Please input again",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

My idea is after dialog showing, put playlist name which user input into QueryMusic.playlistNameList.

But each time below code will be executed before dialog showing. So always get playlistCollection.put null exception error.

```
QueryMusic.playlistCollection.put(QueryMusic.playlistNameList.get(0),tempAdd);
```

Anyone could give me a favor, tell me why and how to fix?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the logcat

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                                        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                        at com.flover.simplemusic.AddToExistedPlaylist$1.onItemClick(AddToExistedPlaylist.java:59)
                                                                        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1188)
                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3105)
                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4096)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                                                                        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:117)
```

Comment: can you please post your logcat output?

Comment: Once keep the following line in Logcat and check weather it contains any value or not.. QueryMusic.playlistNameList.get(0)

Comment: Thanks reply so soon,I have already check these values, only QueryMusic.playlistNameList.get(0) is null, it seems QueryMusic.playlistCollection.put(QueryMusic.playlistNameList.get(0),tempAdd); already being executed before dialog showing, but QueryMusic.playlistNameList.get(0) need get value from user input when dialog showing